# Empty profile after saving

Tags: dashboard

We have small forms (profiles) on the dashboard to create contacts. However, these do not empty after saving, so that inexperienced users do not see the small "saved" note in the corner and press save a thousand times.
Is it possible that the form is emptied after saving?

LG
Gregor

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible with a little bits of a custom JavaScript, however the precise answer depends on your set-up details we do not have much knowledge about.